# Trying to connect to SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to connect to SQL Server and get data. This is what I did, but it's not working:

```
string connectionString;
SqlConnection cnn;

connectionString = @"Data Source=(IP)\PC-NAME\SQLEXPRESS,3306;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=dbase;User ID=sa;Password=password";

cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
cnn.Open();

MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
cnn.Close();
```

Comment: what is your error message?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 18'

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    YeahBoy.Form2.button_login_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Form2.cs
    [External Code]
    YeahBoy.Program.Main() in Program.cs

Comment: I am unable to find the cause by only seeing this message. Is your SQL server running properly?

Comment: Is that port correct? 3306 is usually taken by MySql. In any case that connectionstring seems wrong. It should be xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS, 1433. If you use the IP address there is no PC-NAME. [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/)

Comment: Is your SQL server running properly? Are u able to browse through databases and tables by using SQL Management Studio GUI using the same info?

Comment: I think you have a problem with the connection string.

Comment: never mind I thought sql server and mysql is the same thing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error trying to connect to SQL Server using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813501/error-trying-to-connect-to-sql-server-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code is Correct, except your connection string i think

So, first, connect to your database via server Explorer in VisualStudio\View menu
Then right-click on your database and select properties and check the connection string and copy that for test

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with your connection string.

Check your connection string using [this given example](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/#:~:text=Connect%20via%20an%20IP%20address&text=200.100%2C1433%3BNetwork%20Library%3D,default%20port%20for%20SQL%20Server.):

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial  
Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```